# Running Ordinal Logistic Regressions with Proc Surveylogistic

Tags: statistics, sas

I am running an ordinal logistic regression. My problem is that SAS won't let me specify which value in the dependent categorical variable as my reference.

My code looks like:

```
proc surveylogistic data=mydata;
weight mywgt;
strata mystrata;
domain mydomain;
class depvar (ref="myref") indvar1 (ref="myref1") indvar2 (ref="myref2") /param=ref;
model depvar (order=internal)=indvar1 indvar2;
title 'my model';run;
```

In the class statement I specify that I want "myref" to be the reference for the dependent var which means when I look at the parameter estimates for the Intercepts the value "myref" should be omitted. When I look at the response profile, SAS correctly orders the categories for my dependent var, but no matter what I put in the class or model statement, I keep getting the highest value as my reference for my dependent var.

Does anyone know how I can specify my reference for my dependent var? It occurred to me I could change the order so that the category I want as the reference would have the highest value, but then it wouldn't be ordered correctly so an ordinal logistic regression would be inappropriate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `event=` to specify your ref in the dependent variable.

```
model depvar(event='myref')=indvar1 indvar2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Ordinal Logistic Regressions don't have reference groups for the dependent variable. Only multinomial logistic regressions do, so that's why I couldn't do it.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?